# Filezilla can't connect with TLS on one domain name

Tags: macos, security, ftp, ssl, filezilla

I've two websites:

- one hosting by **OVH**, and I have no problems with connection with Filezilla (I can use **FTP connexion with TLS**)
- one another not hosting by OVH, and when I'm trying to connect with Filezilla, I can just use FTP connexion (**not secured**).

I have Filezilla on **MAC OS X**.

Here is the message when I'm trying to connect with **TLS secure** on the second domain name:

```
Status:         Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status:         Initializing TLS...
Status:         Verifying certificate...
Status:         TLS connection established.
Status:         Connected
Status:         Retrieving directory listing...
Status:         Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.
Command:    LIST
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
Error:          Primary connection and data connection certificates don't match.
Error:          Transfer connection interrupted: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
Response:   226 Transfer complete.
Error:          Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

How to use TLS with the second website ?

Comment: Contact the hosting provider and tell them to fix their configuration?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like multiple problems which might be related to each other or not:

> Status:         Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.

This is usually the case if the server is deployed behind some firewall or NAT router and the server itself does not have a public IP.

> Error:          Primary connection and data connection certificates don't match.

This might be a server which listens on multiple addresses and has different certificates per IP address. Since it is not properly configured to use the correct IP address in the response to PASV command (see above) it might also serve the wrong certificate on this wrong IP address.

If this server is not under your control you need to contact the responsible person to fix the server setup.

Comment: Oh yeah unfortunately, the server isn't under my control... Is this a big mistake to not use TLS ?

Comment: Without TLS username and password and all other traffic are sent in clear and can be sniffed and manipulated by a man in the middle. You have to decide for yourself if this is an acceptable risk. You might check if FileZilla supports the use of TLS for the login only, because then you will not have the problems with the different certificate for the data connection and at least the username and password are protected.

Comment: "username and password and all other traffic are sent in clear and can be sniffed and manipulated by a man in the middle" just when I'm sending files by Filezilla/when Filezilla is open or at everytime with my website ?

Comment: Every time you open FileZilla and connect to the other site data get transferred. This means also when you are just doing a file listing.